# Microsoft VBA Powerpoint IndentLevel not counting properly

Tags: python, vba, powerpoint

I am attempting to write a python script that will access a powerpoint's information and store them into a dictionary. I ran into issues with indented bullets being assigned as dictionary values for the previous bullet seen below:

Title Shape

- Example:

  - Item 1

    - Item 2
  - Item 3
- Next example:

I need it to be listed in the dictionary as

```
Example : [Item 1, Item 2, Item 3]
```

I am using a VBA command via win32com.client and EnsureDispatch. The command is as follows:

```
indent_level = pp.ActivePresentation.Slides(sl).Shapes(sh).TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(pi).IndentLevel
```

with sl, sh, and pi being values for the current slide, shape and paragraph.

However, when running this code, it treats the first bullet of the second shape (containing the content of the slide) as some crazy value. On one computer, it computed the indentlevel value to be 32768 and on the other, -2765987431. Just absurd. It seems to be the first bullet of any shape after the title slide that messes up.

Also, this in turn causes all of the results to delay by 1. I think it is seen easier than explained:

Expected: 1, 2, 3, 2, 1

Actual: 32768, 1, 2, 3, 2

The current result is put in place of the following one. The final result is lost. The first result is replaced with the absurd number. Is there any reason it would be doing this? Or is there a better way to identify indent levels?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out guys. The issue was in my values counting current slide, shape, and paragraph. The command:

Enumerate(x)

Starts counting at 0. The IndentLevel command did not like paragraph 0, and the delay was caused by the fact that the first line is actually paragraph 1. Carry on.